# How to Overlap Parent Div From Child Div

Tags: html, css

I have some divs at my HTML and one of them is loading image div so I want it overlap its parent div. Here is my code:

```
<div id="something1">
    <div id="something2"></div>
    <div id="parent" style="border: 15px solid #c1c1c1;width:200px; height:250px;">
        <div id="child" style="position: absolute; border: 15px solid #a2f2e2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use different positions (i.e. absolute, relative etc.) child div couldn't overlap its parent. Here is my fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/yNFxj/4/ I don't want to see anything from parent div but I want to see that child div increased as parent's size and overlapped it.

Any ideas about how can I dot it just with pure html and css and with a generic way to implement it my any other pages?

**PS:** Border, width, height etc. are just for example, it can be removed.

Comment: How big does this child div need to be?

Comment: @AndyHolmes child div should have the size of its parent.

Comment: you can just add height: 100%; and width: 100%; to the child div. your positioning looks good.

Comment: Oh sorry, with my solution you should change position t relative for the child.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sajjan's the closest from what I can tell, but his has a few flaws:

1. `Position: absolute` requires its parent to have a non-static position (this is often done with `position: relative`, which effectively works the same way as static).
2. You don't need to set the height and width of the child, just the parent.

[Here's my Fiddle for it to demonstrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/d9TLr/2/)

```
#parent {
    border: 5px solid gray;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

The key here is the `position: relative` on the parent.

I am curious, though, what exactly you're trying to achieve with this. I have a feeling that whatever it is, there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesnt this work for you? If i understand you right, you just want to mask the parent DIV with the child DIV?

```
<div id="something1">
  <div id="something2"></div>
  <div id="parent" style="border: 15px solid #c1c1c1;width:200px; height:250px;">
    <div id="child" style="position: absolute; border: 15px solid #a2f2e2;top:0;left:0;width:200px; height:250px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output on chrome:
[image]

To make it generic, get the parents position/dimension using offsetTop/Left/Height/Width methods and set the child's dimensions/position using these, im sure there are plenty of posts on SO that do this..

Comment: It doesn't work, doesn't overlap its parent. Child should be same size with parent and I could not see anything from parent because of it has overlapped.

Comment: @kamaci works for me on chrome and on IE8..http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/d9TLr/

Comment: It works because you are using the body as viewport... try putting `margin: 50px;` to `#parent`, and it will move leaving `#child` behind... in your example, parent and child are totally unrelated, it is a coincidence that they matches

Comment: @SajjanSarkar try that http://jsfiddle.net/NcfCM/ it fails when I put a div top of it?

Comment: @kamaci Ok, im confused, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want the child DIV to have exactly the same size as the parent and have exactly the same position so it perfectly covers the parent? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes and thanks for your help. I have checked your code and it is OK. However why it is failed after I added a div at the top? I am searching for a solution that it doesn't fail when I add something top or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that `absolute` positioned elements refers to the first parent element with a position different from `static`.

This means that if no parents have `fixed`, `relative`, or `absolute` position, it will refer to the body, that is not what you want in this case.

Then put `position: relative;` to your parent div.

Second problem: with absolute position, you can stop using `width` and `height` and start using `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` properties;

Setting all them to `0` means ***extends the object to the parent boundaries***.

But here you want to overlap them, then... simply, use a negative value equals to the size of the parent borders: 15px;

```
top:    -15px;
left:   -15px;    
bottom: -15px;    
right:  -15px;
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/yNFxj/9/

I've used dashed borders so you can see the underneath parent's borders ;)

Comment: If I want to reuse my child css should I update the children css code according to my parent's css?

Comment: When I use it without borders it fails?

Comment: First comment: `absolute` and `fixed` elements should always be handled carefully, they're "portable" if *some* conditions (of the parents, mainly) are the same, unless they will mess up. For the second comment: absolutely not, removing borders of the child will not affect the correct functioning: http://jsfiddle.net/yNFxj/9/ (remove opacity to see only the child background); if you remove the borders from the parent instead, simply transform all the `-15px` to `0;` or to the new parent's border value...

Comment: @kamaci - It seems to me that you're missing some fundamental knowledge of CSS, how it works, and why certain things occur. I recommend working through the [resources at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css) so that you can get a solid understanding of CSS and can figure out on your own why Andrea's solution "fails" when you remove the borders.

Comment: Any feedback ? Are you ok or do you still have problems ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="something1">
<div id="something2"></div>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent { 
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a2f2e2;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Works fine

EDIT: added with and height inherit for you & positioned properly

Comment: I don't want to see anything from parent when child overlapped it but I can see at your solution?

Comment: That's because you need to alter the values to match the parent's size. You can just use width: inherit; height: inherit; on the child div - this will overlay and match the parent div size :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but they are not overlapped exactly :) Child is a bit down left of parent you can see it from here: http://tinkerbin.com/pF3aeFje

Comment: That's because you need to set top and left to 0 - top: 0; left: 0; - ill update

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="something1">
<div id="something2"></div>
<div id="parent" style="border: 15px solid #c1c1c1;position:relative; width:200px; height:250px;">
    <div id="child" style="position: absolute; border: 15px solid #a2f2e2; width:200px; height:250px; left:-15px; top:-15px"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

update a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/yNFxj/16/