# HTML/CSS close button overlapping right/upper corner

Tags: html, css

Looking to place a button overlying, and partially outside parent div such as in this picture. MY attempts have it within the parent DIV. The picture below is what I am after.

[image]

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid Black;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background: #A4D3EE;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
  position: relative;
}

#x {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background: red;
 color: white;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <button id = "x">
            X
        </button>
    Text Text Text
    Text Text Text
    Text Text Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I guess this is what you looking for:

Just add `position:absolute;` instead `relative`

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
  /*border-radius: 25px;*/
  border: 2px solid Black;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background: #A4D3EE;
  overflow: visible;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
  position: relative;
}

#x {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <button id = "x">
            X
        </button>
    Text Text Text
    Text Text Text
    Text Text Text
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed that is what I was after, but In an effort to make the code presentable, somehow the problem dissappeared. I enclosed in another div to show my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/cycle4passion/oa7qe6s6/4/

Comment: The reason is `overflow: auto;`, Change it to `overflow: visible;`.

Comment: How does this work? In my version the position:absolute makes the overlay show up all the way at the top of the page... What trick am I missing? Main difference in my case I'm trying to render a red circle atop a <button>.

Comment: Aaaah!! According to [this answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605639/how-to-overlap-parent-div-from-child-div) "`position: absolute` requires its parent to have a non-static position". Using `position: relative` in the parent made it work for me.

Comment: is use -> position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; for a btn in bootstrap card and work's well. thank you.